# Is there a way to prevent content reflow from lazy-loading images if both max-width and max-height are already set?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

On the website I am working on, I am trying to prevent content reflow from occurring when images load. I'm using React. In my particular situation, my solution must:

- Work with images of different aspect ratios. (e.g. if it's a 3:2 image, it stays 3:2. If it's 16:9, it stays 16:9)
- Support max-height and max-width CSS attributes. (In my case, `max-height = 60vh;` and `max-width = 100%;`, if that helps.)

I have read about the `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` approaches. They do not work because of point #1, since the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` must be hardcoded and the images do not all have the same aspect ratio. When I use JSX to dynamically change the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`, it begins distorting when the image hits the `max-height` or `max-width`. I do not know what else I can do.

Thanks!

Comment: Solved. I used an SVG, like [here](https://camillehdl.dev/inline-svg-prevent-reflow-lazy-loading/). I set the aspect ratio to what I wanted and made it behave like the original image itself. Then I overlaid the original image on top with absolute position.